# Odoo Outgoing Mail Server Error: Connection Test Failed

Tags: odoo, outgoing-mail

My email, my password and everyting is correct. All of my Odoo projects have the same outgoing mail server, but in this one, I don't know what is the cause of this error. Please see the link for the image:

https://snipboard.io/7p8On1.jpg

The error always says:

"Connection Test Failed! Here is what we got instead: -3 Temporary failure in name resolution"

I've already tried a lot of solutions including the Step 2 Verification and some online articles tutorial on ubuntu terminal to solve the problem but still I got an error. Please help me how to solve this?